# Calculating difference that starts over when a two-level factor alternates

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate the difference and then eventually the cumulative sum of the differences of a variable. The calculations are conditional on a factor that has two levels and the computations need to start over each time the factor alternates back-and-forth.

Lets consider `x` to be a time-stamp, and `ant` to be an antenna that detects an individual.

Hopefully my sample data makes this clear.

Using dplyr I've tried `group_by(ant)` but that doesn't start the difference back to zero when the individual is subsequently detected at the other antenna.

I have found other posts describing cumulative sums with restarts but none of them quite get at what I am trying to accomplish.

I am not tied to dplyr, but I am looking for assistance on keeping this scalable.

```
set.seed(14)
test <-  data.frame(x = sort(x= round(runif(20,0, 10), 2), decreasing = 
                    F),
                    ant = sample(c("n", "s"), replace = T, size = 20))

library(dplyr)
test %>%
    group_by(ant) %>%
    mutate(diff = x - lag(x))
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
   x    ant diff
1.64    n   0
2.54    n   0.9
3.53    s   0
3.82    s   0.29
4.28    s   0.46
4.74    s   0.46
4.86    n   0
5.11    s   0
5.53    s   0.42
5.95    n   0
6.38    s   0
6.73    n   0
 7.4    s   0
8.51    s   1.11
8.52    s   0.01
8.57    n   0
8.91    s   0
9.33    n   0
9.57    s   0
9.83    s   0.26
```

From here I should be able to figure out how to get the cumulative sum for each factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution similar to Uwe's, but only using tidyverse functions is

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>%
  mutate(seq_chg = ant != lag(ant)) %>%
  replace_na(list(seq_chg = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(seq_id = cumsum(seq_chg)) %>%
  group_by(seq_id) %>%
  mutate(diff = x - lag(x)) %>%
  replace_na(list(diff = 0))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   seq_id [12]
       x ant   seq_chg seq_id    diff
   <dbl> <fct> <lgl>    <int>   <dbl>
 1  1.64 n     TRUE         1 0      
 2  2.54 n     FALSE        1 0.9    
 3  3.53 s     TRUE         2 0      
 4  3.82 s     FALSE        2 0.29   
 5  4.28 s     FALSE        2 0.46   
 6  4.74 s     FALSE        2 0.46   
 7  4.86 n     TRUE         3 0      
 8  5.11 s     TRUE         4 0      
 9  5.53 s     FALSE        4 0.420  
10  5.95 n     TRUE         5 0      
11  6.38 s     TRUE         6 0      
12  6.73 n     TRUE         7 0      
13  7.4  s     TRUE         8 0      
14  8.51 s     FALSE        8 1.11   
15  8.52 s     FALSE        8 0.01000
16  8.57 n     TRUE         9 0      
17  8.91 s     TRUE        10 0      
18  9.33 n     TRUE        11 0      
19  9.57 s     TRUE        12 0      
20  9.83 s     FALSE       12 0.260
```

Answer (score 2):

We need a grouping by the `run-length-id` of 'ant' to create a unique id whenever the 'ant' value switches to another value.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
test %>% 
  group_by(grp = rleid(ant)) %>% # rleid from data.table
  mutate(diff1 = c(0, diff(x))) %>% 
  #or use the OP's code
  # mutate(diff1 = x - lag(x, default = first(x))) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp) # remove the created grp column
# A tibble: 20 x 4
#       x ant    diff diff1
#   <int> <chr> <int> <int>
# 1     1 n         0     0
# 2     2 s         0     0
# 3     3 s         1     1
# 4     4 n         0     0
# 5     5 s         0     0
# 6     6 n         0     0
# 7     7 s         0     0
# 8     8 s         1     1
# 9     9 s         1     1
#10    10 s         1     1
#11    11 s         1     1
#12    12 n         0     0
#13    13 s         0     0
#14    14 n         0     0
#15    15 s         0     0
#16    16 n         0     0
#17    17 n         1     1
#18    18 n         1     1
#19    19 n         1     1
#20    20 s         0     0
```

#### data

```
test <- structure(list(x = 1:20, ant = c("n", "s", "s", "n", "s", "n", 
"s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "n", "s", "n", "s", "n", "n", "n", "n", 
"s"), diff = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: @akun: Thanks! I thought this was it! Oddly, your answer appeared to work the first time I ran it, after a reboot it did not. Very strange and I can't get it to reproduce the result again with my data.  Now the code you provide does not restart the difference computation with each change in 'ant'. I have edited my question with more complex values for 'x' in hopes to make it more clear what result I am aiming for.

Comment: @akun: I figured it out! There was a conflict with the 'plyr' package loaded

Comment: @Scolopax. If plyr is loaded, then you can use `dplyr::mutate(..`

Comment: @akun: that's helpful information for lots of tasks!  It does work for a solution as does FlorianBrezina's

Answer (score 1):

The OP has requested

> to calculate the difference and then *eventually the cumulative sum of the differences* of a variable. The calculations [...] need to start over when the factor alternates back-and-forth.

#### Computing the differences

The `rleid()` function from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package can be used to identify changes in `ant`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, diff := c(0, diff(x)), by = rleid(ant)]
test
```

> ```
>        x ant diff
>  1: 1.64   n 0.00
>  2: 2.54   n 0.90
>  3: 3.53   s 0.00
>  4: 3.82   s 0.29
>  5: 4.28   s 0.46
>  6: 4.74   s 0.46
>  7: 4.86   n 0.00
>  8: 5.11   s 0.00
>  9: 5.53   s 0.42
> 10: 5.95   n 0.00
> 11: 6.38   s 0.00
> 12: 6.73   n 0.00
> 13: 7.40   s 0.00
> 14: 8.51   s 1.11
> 15: 8.52   s 0.01
> 16: 8.57   n 0.00
> 17: 8.91   s 0.00
> 18: 9.33   n 0.00
> 19: 9.57   s 0.00
> 20: 9.83   s 0.26
> ```

Or, using `shift()`:

```
setDT(test)[, diff := x - shift(x, fill = x[1]), by = rleid(ant)]
```

#### Computing the cumulative sums directly

If I understand correctly, the computation of differences was only meant as an intermediate step to the final calculation of the cumulative sums which *need to start over when the factor alternates back-and-forth*.

This can be done directly because a cumulative sum of differences of `x` is equal to `x` minus the first value of `x` for each streak of identical values of `ant`:

```
setDT(test)[, cumsum := x - x[1L], by = rleid(ant)]
test
```

> ```
>        x ant diff cumsum
>  1: 1.64   n 0.00   0.00
>  2: 2.54   n 0.90   0.90
>  3: 3.53   s 0.00   0.00
>  4: 3.82   s 0.29   0.29
>  5: 4.28   s 0.46   0.75
>  6: 4.74   s 0.46   1.21
>  7: 4.86   n 0.00   0.00
>  8: 5.11   s 0.00   0.00
>  9: 5.53   s 0.42   0.42
> 10: 5.95   n 0.00   0.00
> 11: 6.38   s 0.00   0.00
> 12: 6.73   n 0.00   0.00
> 13: 7.40   s 0.00   0.00
> 14: 8.51   s 1.11   1.11
> 15: 8.52   s 0.01   1.12
> 16: 8.57   n 0.00   0.00
> 17: 8.91   s 0.00   0.00
> 18: 9.33   n 0.00   0.00
> 19: 9.57   s 0.00   0.00
> 20: 9.83   s 0.26   0.26
> ```

Comment: Thanks.  This is close but doesn't calculate the difference between records of variable 'x'. I have edited the post in hopes to clarify the process I'm looking for

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your question and providing a new sample dataset. I have updated my answer which I hope does now meet your requirements.